# Call "error" from "next" function inside observer

Tags: error-handling, rxjs, observable

Lets look at this pseudoCode:

```
obs$.subscribe( response => {

  if (response.statusFlag) {

    console.log('Everything is good');

  } else {

    // I need to switch into the error-part of my observer: pseudoCode
    // I need to go into Error-World
    moveIntoErrorPart();

  }

},
error => {
  console.log('Im in Error-World');
});
```

So in case of

- response.statusFlag = true `// 'Everything is good'`
- response.statusFlag = false `// 'Im in Error-World'`

How can I move from INSIDE `next` into `error` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the logic inside `pipe()`

```
obs$.pipe(
    mergeMap(res => res.statusFlag==true ? of(res) : throwError('error'))
)
.subscribe(...)
```

Comment: seems like a valid approach. Ill mark it as answer if no superior solution arrives.

Comment: Is this `throwError` operator works with this observable: ```observable.subscribe({ next: () => { func1.then().catch(e => throwError(() => e)) }, error: (e) => { console.log(e) }, complete: () => { console.log('completed') } })``` @fan-cheung

Comment: It did not work. in the `func1` if an error throws it won't be catched by error observer. @fan-cheung

Comment: throwError is a rxjs error function it won't work with promise. in promise if you want to rethrow error just do a normal `throw(new Error())`

Answer (score 1):

Doing it in pipe is indeed valid, but I'd word it more like this:

```
obs$.pipe(
    filter(res => res.statusFlag),
    throwIfEmpty(),
)
.subscribe(...)
```

There is a subtle but important difference, in my example : 
If there are multiple emissions, only one successful one is required.
In Fan's example :
If there are multiple emissions, only one failed response is enough to error the whole chain.

This difference won't matter if the obs$ only has one emission, which I guess is probably the case here, but otherwise make sure that you know your use-case.